# Run-Time Error '424' Object Required - MoveFirst Error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a login screen with a dropdown list that has their MSID from Table tTbl_LoginUsers
The MSID corresponds to the PKUserId (which is an integer) like below

```
PKUserID    MSID
1           jjenki02
2           trensc01
```

I need the code below to note the PKUserID to be used for LngLongID, which places the 1 or 2 corresponding PKUSERID to the MSID into my tTbl_LoginSessions in the column fldUserName, but executing this gives me the Run-Time Error '424' Object Required. I cannot for the life of me figure out why? Any ideas?

```
Private Sub CboUser_Click()
Dim MyCon As ADODB.Connection
Dim MyRS As ADODB.Recordset

    Set MyCon = New ADODB.Connection
    MyCon.Open "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=dbswd****;UID=*****;PWD=*****;DATABASE=Regulatory;"
    Set MyRS = New ADODB.Recordset

'/The following code focuses on the DropDown field that the User selects their MSID
'/if MyNum = MSID, then MoveFirst to get the PKUserID(Column 1)from tTbl_LoginUsers
CboUser.SetFocus
MyNum = CboUser.Text
MyRS.Open "Select * from dbo.tTbl_LoginUsers Where MSID = '" & MyNum & "'", MyCon
Debug.Print strSQL

NewRecordRS.MoveFirst

LngLoginId = NewRecordRS!fldUserName


End Sub
```

NEW ADJUSTED CODE: 
tTbl_LoginSessions has the following fields: fldloginkey, fldUserName, fldLoginEvent, fld LogoutEvent, fldComputerName.
.MoveFirst triggers it

```
Private Sub CboUser_Click()
Dim MyCon As ADODB.Connection
Dim MyRS As ADODB.Recordset

    Set MyCon = New ADODB.Connection
    MyCon.Open "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=dbswd0027;UID=Mickey01;PWD=Mouse02;DATABASE=Regulatory;"
    Set MyRS = New ADODB.Recordset

With MyRS
'/The following code focuses on the DropDown field that the User selects their MSID
'/if that MyNum = MSID, then MoveFirst to get the PKUserID(Column 1)from tTbl_LoginUsers
     CboUser.SetFocus
     MyNum = CboUser.Text
     MyRS.Open "Select * from dbo.tTbl_LoginUsers Where MSID = '" & MyNum & "'", MyCon
     Debug.Print strSQL

   If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
        .MoveFirst
        LngLoginId = !fldUserName
    End If
End With
Debug.Print strSQL
'NewRecordRS.MoveFirst
'LngLoginId = NewRecordRS!fldUserName


End Sub
```

THIS IS THE CODE that places that PKUSERID into the Login Sessions:

```
Function CreateSession()
'/This function records the details regarding the login details of the person

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strSQL As String
Dim WhoAmI As Long

Set NewIdentRS = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim LngLoginId As String, StrComputerName As String


'passing variables
StrMSID = LngLoginId
'old StrMSID = StrLoginName
StrComputerName = FindComputerName

   'Declaring what table you are passing the variables to
    strSQL = "Insert into dbo.tTbl_LoginSessions(fldUserName, fldLoginEvent, fldComputerName) Values ('" & StrMSID & "','" & Now() & "','" & StrComputerName & "')"
     Debug.Print strSQL

    'connect to SQL Server
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    With con
        .ConnectionString = cSQLConn
        .Open
    End With

    'write back
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .Execute


    End With

    con.Close
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing



End Function
```

I also have this:

```
Public Function GrabMSID(frmObject)
GrabMSID = LngUserID
End Function
'Call it this way:
MyMSID = GrabMSID(Me)


Option Compare Database
Public LngLoginId As Long
```

Comment: Insert into dbo.tTbl_LoginSessions(fldUserName, fldLoginEvent, fldComputerName) Values ('','11/4/2013 9:38:26 AM','LH7U0CNU139430Z')
The code works great to put the date/time and Users machine, but the first quotes should have the integer that we are trying to get through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.MoveFirst` line throws an error because you have no variable named *NewRecordRS*.  Looks like you need this instead ...

```vb
'NewRecordRS.MoveFirst
MyRS.MoveFirst
```

Or consider using the recordset object variable name once in a `With` block ...

```vb
With MyRS
    .Open "Select * from dbo.tTbl_LoginUsers Where MSID = '" & _
        MyNum & "'", MyCon
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
        .MoveFirst
        LngLoginId = !fldUserName
    End If
End With
```

Note: If *tTbl_LoginUsers* does not include a field named *fldUserName*, that code will throw an error (*"Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal"*) at this line:

```vb
        LngLoginId = !fldUserName
```

However, I attempted to solve the "object required" error which was the original subject of your question.  If you then encounter an error because *fldUserName* does not exit in the recordset, that is a different error.

Comment: Great, I used the With block and now I am getting a Run-time error '3265': Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal. I checked all the formats, all integers.

Comment: We need more information to diagnose that error.  Which line triggers the error?  Does the table include a field named *fldUserName*?

Comment: tTbl_LoginSessions has the following fields: fldloginkey, fldUserName, fldLoginEvent, fld LogoutEvent, fldComputerName.

Comment: In that case, you should get an error at `MyRS.Open` because the query includes "Where MSID = " and you just showed us that the table does not include a field named *MSID*.

Comment: Sorry, tTbl_LoginUsers does have the following columns: PKUserID, MSID, ACtive, fldLoggedIn, fldComputer, strEmpEmail, strEmpEmail, strEmpFirstName, strEmpLastName. I am trying to lookup the MSID on this table, grab the corresponding PKUserID and place it in fldUserName to be used to log users out. Does that help? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: What? Earlier you said the table includes a field named *fldUserName*.  If that field is not present in the table, you will definitely trigger an error at `LngLoginId = !fldUserName`

Comment: Three Tables:
tTbl_LoginsPermissions - irrelevant right now
tTbl_LoginSessions has fldUserName
tTbl_LoginUsers has PKUserID and MSID
When a person logs in, I am looking up the MSID field, Lookfirst to PKUserID to grab the Autonumber Integer and place that autonumber into the fldUserName. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: OK, thanks, I got it to work! Woot Woot. Still not able to pass the variable to the login Session, which is another topic.
And the Passing works now. Thank you for the code and diggin deeper.